# A function use statement without closures in PHP

Tags: php, closures, scope, global, anonymous-function

So I have a function that outputs a form for editing the user's profile:

This isn't my actual code, it's sort of PHP pseudocode.

**functions.php**

```
function edit_user_form () {
    $mode = 'edit';
    $user_id = get_user_id();

    include dirname(__FILE__).'/user-form.php';
}

function create_user_form () {
    $mode = 'create';
    include dirname(__FILE__).'/user-form.php';
}
```

**user-form.php**

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/classes/Form.php';
$form = new Form();
?>
<form method="post">
    <?php print $mode == 'edit' ? '<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="'.$user_id.'">' : ''; ?>
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
<?php
$form->validation_callback = function ($form) use ($mode) {
    if ($mode == 'edit' && !isset($_POST['user_id'])) {
        $form->trigger_error('The user_id parameter was not sent.');
    }
}
```

My question is: if I'm using an older version of PHP that doesn't implement closure (anonymous functions), and I were to replace those last few lines with, say:

```
if (!function_exists('my_validation_callback')) {
    function my_validation_callback ($form) {
        // How do I access $mode here?
    }
}
$form->validation_callback = 'my_validation_callback';
```

How would I access the variable `$mode` in the context of my function? Obviously `global $mode;` wouldn't work, as `$mode` is not a global variable.

Comment: `global $mode` should work. While it is not global, it is in a parent scope of the function definition. Even better though, would be to just pass mode into the function itself. Perhaps work out a small standard that you have a second parameter that is an associative array of values. Or even just pass in the value always. User defined functions don't care if you pass in extra arguments. They are just ignored if the argument isn't in the definition.

Comment: `global` wouldn't work, as demonstrated here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/wLD1Ke . Ideally, I don't want to have to change the class that runs `call_user_func`, but I may have to.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have some kind of objection to using first class objects, then you can simply make a class that has the function..

```
class FormValidator{

    protected $mode;

    public function setMode($mode) {
        $this->mode = $mode;
    }
    function validateForm($form) {

        $somethingToCheck = $this->mode;
    }

}
```

Inside you code that ads the validator do this

```
//replace this
//$form->validation_callback = function ($form) use ($mode) {
//with this
$formValidator = new FormValidator();
$formValidator->setMode($mode);
$form->validator = $formValidator;
```

Then instead of calling a callback, you just call the method on the object you were passed.
Its only about 6 extra lines of code, and now you also have a first class object.

Inside your Form class, instead of calling the callback, call the class with a defined method

```
//call_user_func($this->validationCallback, $this);

$this->validator->validateForm($this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `create_function` and insert the mode into the code of the function:

```
$form->validation_callback = create_function('$form', '$mode = "'.$mode.'";
    if ($mode == "edit" && !isset($_POST["user_id"])) {
        $form->trigger_error("The user_id parameter was not sent.");
    }
');
```

But since all you're doing is checking if `$mode` is `'edit'`, and if not, not doing anything, why not just do something like

```
if ($mode == 'edit') {
    $form->validation_callback = create_function('$form', '
        if (!isset($_POST["user_id"])) {
            $form->trigger_error("The user_id parameter was not sent.");
        }
    ');
}
```